# An object depends on the gc root object, such as a thread field，what is the gc of this object？

Tags: java, garbage-collection

refer to the ThreadPoolExecutor's Worker class

```java
      private final class Worker
        extends AbstractQueuedSynchronizer
        implements Runnable
    {

        final Thread thread;

        Runnable firstTask;

        volatile long completedTasks;


        Worker(Runnable firstTask) {
            setState(-1); // inhibit interrupts until runWorker
            this.firstTask = firstTask;
            this.thread = getThreadFactory().newThread(this);
        }

        /** Delegates main run loop to outer runWorker  */
        public void run() {
            runWorker(this);
        }
    }
```

this is some code segment in ThreadPoolExecutor class

```java
    private boolean addWorker(Runnable firstTask, boolean core) {
        boolean workerStarted = false;
        boolean workerAdded = false;
        Worker w = null;
        try {
            w = new Worker(firstTask);
            final Thread t = w.thread;
            ...
        }
    }
```

I learned through Google that Thread is a gc root, The worker depends on the thread object, and the thread also depends on the worker. When the thread is running, if the worker will be recycled, I know, marked only if the object is unreachable relative to gc root, how does the worker determine that the worker should be marked for recycling. Otherwise, the worker will not be recycled while the thread is running？

Comment: Please post the relevant code inline.

Comment: Worker is a Runnable, and a Thread holds a Runnable.

Comment: Runnable also holds this Thread.Involving the thread,  I do not know how worker or thread are gc?

Comment: 'How does the worker determine ...'? It doesn't. GC does. The remainder of your question makes no ascertainable sense.

Comment: I just want to know if the recycling of a worker object depends on the death or operation of the thread object?

Comment: Of course, among other things, as the thread is a GC root, as you have already noted yourself, but if you're using a thread pool there is no thread death. Unclear what you're actually asking here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one Garbage Collector during the lifetime of a JVM.

Consider reading this [Java Garbage Collection Basics](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/gc01/index.html) to get more info on GC.

**UPDATE:**

You write:
"The worker depends on the thread object, and the thread also depends on the worker".

So how does the GC can remove either of them if you can reach them at any moment (which means the objects can still be in use)?

The objects will stay in memory ***untill*** they become unreachable.

So in your case the Thread and the Worker will be garbage collected only when they both become unreachable from the root.

Comment: Excuse me, I re-edited my question, your current answer can't find the answer I want.

Comment: @王星宇 You need to consider the strong possibilty that the answer you want isn't the answer you're going to get.

Comment: If it is two ordinary objects, then of course. When it comes to threads, I want to know what happens to a dependent thread object, or whether it will die if the worker is recycled. Of course, this is the premise that workers are being recycled, or is the thread's activity status not allowed to be recycled by workers?

Comment: Thread is an ordinary object too. "whether it will die if the worker is recycled" - it may die and it may not die. It all depends on whether the Thread object is still reachable after Worker is recycled. JVM takes care of such reference resolutions for you, so there is nothing you should worry about.

Comment: @ Pavel Smirnov  So in fact, this thread is also used as a normal object for gc without complicating simple problems. I think I understand. but,I first used Stack Overflow, how will I be sure of your answer?

Comment: @王星宇 The thread will die when it exits. The thread pool will inhibit this. The worker has nothing to do with that whatsoever, but the worker cannot be GC'd before the thread. It remains unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 You mean that workers will be recycled, and the running thread will not

Comment: @王星宇 Don't tell me what I mean. I meant what I said. Exactly that, and nothing more. I am still unable to determine what you're talking about. For example, what do you mean by 'recycle'?

Comment: @user207421 Simple words, if A has B, B is a gc root。 In particular, B is a thread and is running, when A will be recycled

Comment: @user207421 recycle is gc

Comment: Simple words. What do you mean by 'recycle'? And what do GC roots have to do with it?

Comment: No, 'recycle' is *not* GC. It would really help if you said what you actually mean, and didn't misuse standard terminology. An object that is reachable from a GC root cannot be GC'd. OK? If that doesn't answer your question, I have no idea what you're asking. And if it does, you essentially said the same thing in your question, so again I don't know why you're asking.

Comment: @user207421 Sorry, my English is very bad. These are the ones I translated through Google.

Comment: @user207421 I am sorry to have troubled you.,I have a misconception that an object is GC'd, then the memory data of all its fields will be GC‘d’. I think the correct result should be to only GC the memory area allocated by the object. The basic data type field The value should still be in the constant pool (including String), and the GC of the reference object is irrelevant to this object, Is it right?

Comment: @王星宇 up to this point, no constant pool was involved in this Q&A. However, you now got it right, the garbage collector will reclaim the memory of an object when not needed anymore, which does not affect any other object that might have been formerly referenced by that object. In this regard, a JVM may detect that an object’s memory is not needed anymore, even when the object itself seems to be in use (naively considered reachable), as optimized code may work without touching the memory. But you will not recognize the difference, which is what automatic memory management is all about.

Comment: @Holger thank you , i got it, constant pool is an example,